# Is there any analog of QuokkaJs for Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I'm learning algorithms and I was wondering if there is any analog of QuokkaJs for Dart? It's a convenient plugin for IDEs.

Comment: Check out: https://dartpad.dev/

Comment: dartpad is not what I need, thanks tho